# Video skipping on ubuntu 16.04 after updates

Tags: vlc

VLC and all video started skipping after latest rounds of updates (10-15-16).  This happened on my laptop (AMD) and my home computer (intel).  After much searching and trying different things I found the fix.  This is for all you trying to find a fix for it.  It seems that the new updates do not include cpu specific codes.

So to fix go to software & Updates.  Go to additional drivers.  Select the proprietary Processor microcode driver. This fixed both my laptop and desktop.

Hope this will help so no one else has to search the net for days to fix.

Comment: This was across multiple desktops.  I have Unity, KDE and Cinnamon.  Using Cinnamon now.